# Safari Adds Trailing Slash

Tags: asp.net, safari, seo, url-rewrite-module

I've got an ASP.NET website that uses URLRewrite 2 to remove trailing slashes from the URL.

We noticed that Safari on Mac does not obey this rule. It always leaves the trailing slash in the URL. SEO Moz is showing both URLs which appears to be a potential duplicate content issue.

Here is the URLRewrite rule in our Web.Config

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)/$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
 </rule>
```

Here is the website in question: http://www.kurtzandblum.com/ (the slash will be removed except in Safari)

I'm trying to decide if...

1. This is a harmless bug in Safari?
2. My rewrite script is flawed.
3. I should switch it to "add" trailing slashes.

Google says slash or no slash will work http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: This "bug" (?) is surely not "harmless" for me, it has wrecked my application. When the browser accesses site.com/admin.php, Safari is requesting site.com/admin.php/ which is not the being interpreted as the same thing by the server! Thanks for helping in understanding what's happening. Maybe I should try to remove trailing slashes (without redirecting) in .htaccess, a bit like what you're doing.

Comment: By "not obeying that rule", you mean it does not redirect or that it redirects but requests the same URL again, with the trailing slash? Since the second case would be a case of infinite recursion, I suppose you mean the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just how Safari is handling URLs. There is no impact on SEO, so you don't need to do anything.

Your URLs are looking fine in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I suspect the same thing. We are looking further into it. If we determine that there is no seo impact I'll mark this as the answer...

Comment: That is the case. Safari is just a browser. It is in no way tied to Googlebot, indexing, or Google. Your .htaccess is redirecting just fine, you have nothing to worry about.